# Char array is not working in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have the following code:

```
template <typename M>
struct Matrix
{
Matrix(int size);//(int x = defaultRows, int y = defaultCols);
~Matrix();

int rowSize;
int colSize;
char alpha[4];

int getSize() const;
void displayAll();
M getElement(int x, int y);

M** aMatrix;
};


template <typename M>
Matrix<M>::Matrix(int size)
{
alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

rowSize = size;
colSize = size + 1;
aMatrix = new M*[rowSize];

srand(time(NULL)); //set the random seed

for(int r = 0; r < size; r++)
{
    aMatrix[r] = new M[colSize];
    for(int c = 0; c < colSize; c++)
    {
        int randomNum = rand() % 19 + (-9);
        aMatrix[r][c] = randomNum;
    }
}
}
```

I don't know why, but i keep getting errors when I try to complie the program. Its to do with my "alpha" char array (when I comment it out, it works fine).

I don't see whats wrong with it at all...

The errors are:
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '{'

Don't think I have missed anything out have I??

Comment: `alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};` - you can't initialize an array like this after you have already declared it elsewhere. You have to do it all in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in C++ (well not for some time anyway):

```
alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

It looks like an initializer but it's not. Try:

```
alpha[0] = 'a';
alpha[1] = 'b';
alpha[2] = 'c';
alpha[3] = 'd';
```

#### EDIT

Not that it will help you much but C99 (along with some C++ compilers, as an extension)  supports this:

```
alpha = (char[]){'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

Comment: Damn... that means I will end up having 26 lines just for the alphabets... Anyway, Thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't set arrays that way. It's an unfortunate problem with C++ that's fixed in C++11, but for now you have to do something like:

```
alpha[0] = 'a';
alpha[1] = 'b';
...
```

or you can do

```
Matrix<M>::Matrix(int size)
{
    char alpha_init[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    std::copy(alpha_init,alpha_init+4,alpha);
```

In C++11 you will be able to do:

```
Matrix<M>::Matrix(int size)
  : alpha{'a','b','c','d'}
{
```

or even more simply (as Michael Price suggests):

```
struct Matrix {
    /* ... */
    char alpha[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    /* ... */
};
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is solved in C++11.  You could also use the in-class-declaration initialization instead of the constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

```
alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

Arrays can only be initialized that way within its definition. When an array is a member of a class, that form of initialization cannot be used. You will have to do it the regular way, one element at a time:

```
alpha[0] =  'a';
alpha[1] =  'b';
alpha[2] =  'c';
alpha[3] =  'd';
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's have pointed out, this syntax would only work to initialize an array, and by the time you get into the constructor body, the array is already initialized. C++11 has a nice syntax for letting you initialize arrays in the initializer list, but that may or may not yet be available for your C++ compiler.

The other's recommendations work, but I would not suggest them. They're verbose and look a bit ugly mostly, and they will not work with arbitrarily large arrays because at some point the whole thing just becomes unwieldy. So here's what I would do...

```
   static const char alpha_init[] = "abcd";
   ::std::copy(alpha_init, alpha_init+4, alpha);
```